# Problem with case statement, i get a syntax error

Tags: sql, syntax, case

I'm trying to make a case to create a new column on a table. I'm not finding the problem, any help?

Thanks

```sql
SELECT
    R.client AS Client
    CASE Client 
        WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS 'Real Clients'
FROM Request R
```

Comment: .., CASE WHEN  Client is not null..

Comment: ... and there should be a comma after `AS Client`, since fields must be separated by commas and the CASE statement count as a field too

Comment: and tag your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is right syntax:

```
SELECT
    R.client AS Client
    ,CASE WHEN Client IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Real Clients'
FROM Request R
```